# Why is nothing displaying when use the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I run the code nothings changes and nothing works, the JavaScript does not do anything not even run the alerts. The ranges in the HTML are supposed to go into a function that gets their value and outputs it to a `<div>`. That does not happen
This is the JavaScript

```js
$(startup);
    function startup(){
    
    $("#speedRange").change(srange);
    $("#LimitRange").change(lrange);
    $("#ticketbtn").cick(findfine);
    $("#ticketreset").click(reset);
    }
    var speed;
    var limit;
    function srange() {
      speed = $("#speedRange").val();
      speed = Number(speed);
      $("#YourSpeed").html(speed);
    
    function lrange() {
      limit = $("#LimitRange").val();
      limit = Number(limit);
      $("#OverSpeed").html(limit);
    function findfine() {
      alert("ll")
    }
    function reset() {
      alert("ll")
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Speeding Ticket Calculator</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Speeding Ticket Calculator</h1>
        <table id="speedtable">
          <tr>
            <td>Select Your Speed<br>40 <input type="range" id="speedRange"> 160 </td>
            <td><div id="YourSpeed"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Select The Speed Limit<br>40 <input type="range" id="limitRange"> 100 </td>
            <td><div id="OverSpeed"></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table><br>
        <a id="ticketbtn" class="button1">Calculate Penalty</a>
        <a id="ticketreset" class="button1">Reset</a><br>
        <br><br><br>
        <div id="finebox">
    
        </div>
    
        <script src="script.js">
        <p id="demo"></p>
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is the Html

Comment: `$(...).cick` is not a function ... Perhaps an error message is displayed, have you peek the DevConsole?

Comment: Open your dev console. You have several syntax errors like typos in method names, functions without a closing brace, etc... And please do not use hyperlinks as buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery [On API](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to be used in latest version of jquery.

and some function braces where missing,
find the working snippet below.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    debugger;
    startup();


});
        function startup(){
      debugger;
            $("#speedRange").on('change',srange);
            $("#limitRange").on('change',lrange);
            $("#ticketbtn").on('click',findfine);
            $("#ticketreset").on('click',reset);
            }
    var speed;
    var limit;
    
    function srange() {
    debugger
      speed = $("#speedRange").val();
      speed = Number(speed);
      $("#yourSpeed").html(speed);
      }
    
    function lrange() {
    debugger
      limit = $("#limitRange").val();
      limit = Number(limit);
      $("#overSpeed").html(limit);
      }
      
    function findfine() {
    debugger
      alert("ll")
    }
    
    function reset() {
    debugger;
      alert("ll");
       $("#overSpeed").html('');
       $("#yourSpeed").html('');
       
      
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Speeding Ticket Calculator</h1>
        <table id="speedtable">
          <tr>
            <td>Select Your Speed<br>40 <input type="range" id="speedRange"> 160 </td>
            <td><div id="yourSpeed"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Select The Speed Limit<br>40 <input type="range" id="limitRange"> 100 </td>
            <td><div id="overSpeed"></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table><br>
        <a id="ticketbtn" class="button1">Calculate Penalty</a>
        <a id="ticketreset" class="button1">Reset</a><br>
        <br><br><br>
        <div id="finebox">
    
        </div>
    
        
        <p id="demo"></p>
```